# Import .TLB file gives "cannot open source file x.tlh"

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2019

I'm updating a VS2010 C++ project to VS2019.

The project is importing several tlb files, and for each of these, VS2019 is giving an error that it "cannot open source file" for the .tlh file.

One of these is from a DLL that I've also upgraded (written in C#, built and registered OK in VS2019), and 2 others are 3rd party tlb files.

Here's an example of the import statement (in my header file)...

```
#import "../ExcelInterop/bin/Debug/ExcelInterop.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, no_namespace, named_guids
```

The relative path is correct from the header file location.

How do I fix this error, and get VS2019 to correctly process my .tlb files?

Comment: Such a mishap is going to generate a *lot* of error messages, high odds that you're focusing on the wrong one.  Could be as simple as a build order problem or forgetting to run VS elevated.  Copy/paste the first 5 errors and warnings you see into your question, don't obfuscate them.

Comment: Also, delete all of your intermediate and output directories to clear any cached information that might be there from a build with VS2010.

Comment: It took a while to get back to this situation, but yes I think you are right.  I've revisited this in a new environment, and with a clean setup, the error is not happening.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1961169 Could you please elaborate more on how you solved the issue? I have the exact problem and nthg is working..

Comment: I have the project stored in SVN, so I deleted everything, checked out the latest update from SVN.  I may have also reinstalled VS - I can't remember exactly when I did that, but it would have been around the time of this issue.  I hope you manage to get it sorted.

Comment: @Peter hello did you figure out how to solve this? If so can you help me out?

Comment: What I did was I just ignored the error and compiled it and it worked! The red squiggly line never goes away.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a workaround. If you #import XXX.dll and the compiler complains about that it "cannot open source file XXX.tlh", just add this line above the #import line:

#include "[full path of XXX.tlh]"

and comment out the #import line. It should now pass the compilation because the file XXX.tlh does exist. Once successful, revert your code back to the original.

Comment: Issue was the same for me....

#import somepath\xxx.tlb

Error said:
cannot open source file "otherPath!!!!\x86\Debug\xxx.tlh

once I followed jgong workaround with the include for xxx.tlh on the other path it worked to include the xxx.tlb