# Import .tlb, Generated .tlh Gives: forward declaration of enum type is nonstandard

Tags: c++, reference, visual-studio-2017, com, dependencies

I'm reusing a code I wrote couple years ago on a different version of Visual Studio, now Im trying to do it in VS 2017. The code aims to connect different applications using server-client arrangement.I'm accessing the .tlb of one application but I cannot establish the connection (either error of non-accessible .tlh or just no identification of different application methods/properties) , among 254 others. 
The question is similar to this one: [Import .TLB file gives "cannot open source file x.tlh"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751715/import-tlb-file-gives-cannot-open-source-file-x-tlh)

I have tried adding the .tlb file in additional library directories but even when the error disappears, the code still doesnot recognize many methods that were fine before. #import statement shows no errors, yet the generated .tlh file has the following error:

> forward declaration of enum type is nonstandard
>   Hence, It doesnot compile

Other issues also appeared, such as this:

> no instance of function template "IID_PPV_ARGS_Helper" matches the argument list

for this line:

```
HRESULT hr = hyStream->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&Strm));
```

Now, the whole project was running seamlessly back then. I copied three classes with their headers to a new project, so maybe dependencies are the source of errors? Should I add .tlb file in library dependencies of the project?

Any comment is highly appreciated..

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your import statement？When the compiler encounters the #import statement, it generates a wrapper class for the interface in the reference component type library. The #import statement is actually equivalent to executing the API function LoadTypeLib(). They generate intelligent pointers for each interface, declare various interface methods, enumeration types, CLSID, and create a series of wrapper methods.

Comment: @SuarezZhou-MSFT Thank you for your reply, I'll update my question to include that piece of infor

Comment: **"forward declaration of enum type is nonstandard Hence"**:Previously, the reason enum types could not be forward declared is because the size of the enumeration depends on its contents. But now You can forward-declare an enum in C++0x, so long as you declare its storage type at the same time. I suggest you could refer ti the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c